How to Implement Welch's Method for Power Spectral Density Estimation Using PyTorch with CUDA?
I am trying to implement Welch's method for power spectral density (PSD) estimation using PyTorch tensors and CUDA for GPU acceleration. I want to obtain a result similar to the scipy.signal.welch function.
My current implementation is the following (fs=100, nperseg=100, noverlap=50, nfft=256)
def welch_psd(x, fs=1.0, nperseg=256, noverlap=None, nfft=None):
    if noverlap is None:
        noverlap = nperseg // 2
    if nfft is None:
        nfft = nperseg

    batch_size, signal_len = x.size()   #x shape: [-1, 600]

    # Window function
    window = torch.hann_window(nperseg, periodic=False).to(x.device)
    # Calculate the number of segments
    step = nperseg - noverlap
    shape = (batch_size, (x.size(1) - noverlap) // step, nperseg)   #shape shape: [-1, 11, 100]
    strides = (x.stride(0), x.stride(1) * step, x.stride(1))    #strides shape: [600, 50, 1]
    segments = torch.as_strided(x, size=shape, stride=strides)  #segments shape: [-1, 11, 100]

    # Apply window to each segment
    segments = segments * window

    # Compute FFT and power spectral density
    fft_segments = torch.fft.rfft(segments, n=nfft)
    psdx = (1 / (fs * nfft)) * torch.abs(fft_segments)**2
    psdx[..., 1:-1] *= 2  # Double the power except for the DC and Nyquist components

    # Average over segments
    psd = psdx.mean(dim=1)

    # Frequency axis
    freqs = torch.fft.rfftfreq(nfft, 1 / fs).to(x.device)

    return freqs, psd

However, my custom implementation still does not match the results from scipy.signal.welch.
Any insights into what might be going wrong would be very helpful. Thank you!
